# layout_gravity not working in horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have been trying to use `layout_gravity` in a horizontal `linear layout`. But it doesn't seem to work. I **don't** want to use a `relative layout` or any other layout. I want to know why it is not working with `linear layout`.I have earlier used `layout_gravity` in `vertical` linear layouts and it has worked in the way I expected.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="shata1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="shata2"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the the linear layout has a `orientation=horizontal` and `width=match_parent`(it is just inside the root layout). But both the TextViews are displayed sticking to the left of the `LinearLayout`even though I have given their `layout_gravity=center` and `layout_gravity=right` respectively.

Comment: It will not work because the Textview's layout is bounded to `wrap_content` not `match_parent`

Comment: Linear layout doesn't work you want. You should use relative layout. Why don't you want to use relative layout?

Comment: layout_gravity in a LinearLayout can only change the objects position perpendicular to the orientation. If orientation is horizontal, you can specify top and bottom, not left and right.

Comment: @chitti : But I have seen layout_gravity=bottom work in veritcal linear layouts.

Comment: @Ashwin you may want to check that again. You may have seen gravity = bottom for the linear layout work.

Answer (score 60):

Short answer: If you have a horizontal LinearLayout, then each child can only have `layout_gravity` values of `top`, `bottom`, and `center`.

The reason for this is because you've already told the `LinearLayout` to align each child horizontally, left-to-right in the order you specify, which means that it only lets you specify the vertical alignment of each child in the `layout_gravity` parameter, and the opposite applies when your `LinearLayout` is vertical.

There's a good link explaining how the various gravities work [here](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html).

Comment: Even I thought so, at first. But by that logic, vertical LinearLayout should only take values of left, right and center. But vertical layout reacts to the attribute bottom as well.

Comment: I'd be interested to see an example where vertical responds to `bottom`, because as far as my understanding goes, it shouldn't, and it may just be an artefact of the weights assigned to the other children.

Answer (score 11):

As an addition to [Matt Taylor's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33076189/3580745), you can specify the size ratio of the elements inside the layout using the `layout_weight` property. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) for more details.

The code above will split the horizontal space in three equals areas.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

So in this example

- the first element looks like `layout_gravity="left"`
- the second element looks like `layout_gravity="center"`
- the third element looks like `layout_gravity="right"`

Comment: Thomas, the layout_weight of your bottom TextView is missing the closing double-quote (after the 1).  Just fyi.

Comment: Very Limited practicality. Cuz what if you wanna have two elements on the left side (one after another) and one element on the right side???

Answer (score 3):

you can divide layout to 3 part then in right part put "shata2" in center part put "shata1" and left part put a transparent view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="shata1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#111" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_imageview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="shata2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



</LinearLayout>
```

but in your code when you use linear layout it just put views one after other and it doesnt care the layout gravity.
hope it be useful .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have your child view centered then you just need to give your linear layout gravity for the children. On your linear layout set the following:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

I hope I got your question right.

Answer (score 0):

One way for creating three childs in horizontal linearlayout would be(tested):

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Blankets &amp;  Carpets" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_home_feature"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```