# layout_gravity doesn't work with Horizontal orientation in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I want to align text and an image in a `LinearLayout` in the same line. I thought of using `layout_gravity` option for the `TextView` and `ImageView` within a `LinearLayout` with `orientation=horizontal` but it doesn't seem to work. Any reason why is that?

Apparently, `layout_gravity` works only with `orientation=vertical`.

I can do it use multiple linear layouts within the main linear layout but was looking at an elegant way to do it.

Here is the code for the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#e3e2ad"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Layout's Vertical Orientation" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#bcf5b1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="left" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/pigeon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d6c6cd"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Layout's Horizontal Orientation" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#bcf5b1"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:text="left" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:src="@drawable/pigeon"/>
                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the output:
[image]

I have already checked the answer to this question here but it didn't solve this problem. [Difference between gravity and layout_gravity on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-on-android)

Comment: Use Relative layout or Constraint Layout.

Answer (score 1):

replace this layout with your code and change weight according to your requirement 
you have to pass `android:layout_weight` to your child view

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="Layout's Vertical Orientation"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:background="#bcf5b1"
        android:text="left" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/pigeon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think the weights are doing the trick here irrespective of using layout_gravity. My question was targeted more at why layout_gravity doesn't work in the horizontal orientation of linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use Another Relative layout inside the linear layout and add your textview and imageview under it. Then you will get them aligned in the same line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#e3e2ad"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Layout's Vertical Orientation" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#bcf5b1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="left" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/pigeon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#d6c6cd"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Layout's Horizontal Orientation" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                 <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#bcf5b1"
                            //android:layout_weight="0.5"

                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:text="left" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            //android:layout_weight="0.5"

                            android:src="@drawable/pigeon"/>

                           </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also try adding weights that i mentioned above in comments. That would help

Answer (score 0):

you can use RelativeLayout,   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" ontrol is to the right of the parent control。

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#bcf5b1"
            android:text="left" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work. Was wondering why it doesn't work with linear layout in horizontal orientation?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have researched, you have already told it by specifying horizontal that you want the contents to be aligned left-to-right, so the only options `layout_gravity` can specify is vertical alignment like `top` or `bottom`. I'd highly recommend the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076051/layout-gravity-not-working-in-horizontal-linear-layout). The short answer may be that yes, you have to specify `vertical` orientation even though (I think) you want to specify a layout for landscape screen mode.

If you want different properties for vertical vs. horizontal orientation, [you need to create two separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode), one in `/res/layout-land`.

This is all the more confusing considering some questions ask about vertical vs. horizontal *layout* instead of portrait (vertical) vs. landscape (horizontal) *screen orientation* so I don't blame you for not having a straight answer.

In addition, I would suggest using RelativeLayout or the purportedly more efficient [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) which may take some time to get used to but may be the elegant solution you're looking for.