# Layout_gravity start & end doesn't spread the elements to two side, but packed close

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <com.google.android.libraries.onegoogle.account.particle.AccountParticle
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/part_a"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start" />
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/part_b"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would expect `part_a` to be aligned to the right and `part_b` aligned to the left. (Thanks to `android:layout_gravity`).

Why do I see them packed closed to each other?

[image]

Comment: check [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) you can achieve this by `layout_weight` or using other layout like `constraintLayout` or `relativeLayout`

Comment: @MohammedAlaa but then what's the meaning of `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"` ?

Comment: `end` and `start` parameters works only when the `android:orientation` for LinearLayout  is `vertical`

Comment: @MohammedAlaa really? where have you seen that?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076051/layout-gravity-not-working-in-horizontal-linear-layout)